# Como puedo agregar una fuente con mi aplicación de escritorio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, fuentes, windows-installer

Me pasa esto, tengo una aplicación de escritorio pero necesito un tipo especial de fuente que no se encuentra en las almacenadas por defecto de windows, pero se requiere para todo el proyecto, la pregunta es...

Como puedo mediante windows installer instalar este tipo de fuente en cualquier computador donde se instale mi aplicación de escritorio.

Actualmente para hacerlo estoy utilizando **PrivateFontCollection** la cual mediante una carpeta que he creado con las fuentes la obtiene y crea una referencia de ella

```
private readonly PrivateFontCollection typeFont = new PrivateFontCollection();
```

Luego de esto agrego la fuente que quiere agregar

```
typeFont.AddFontFile("Fonts/typeFont-Bold.ttf");
```

Y esto sirve, pero no puedo diseñar mi aplicación de esta forma, ya que por el tamaño o la misma tipografia los elementos crecen mas y terminan ocupando espacios o lugares que no se me sriven.

Alguna idea?

Comment: como creas el instalador del "windows installer" que mencionas ? usas un Setup project, o espor medio de otro soft

Comment: Exacto, uso un setup project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias aplicar lo que se explica aqui

[Installing font using C# setup project](https://jgvimalan.wordpress.com/2011/02/22/installing-font-using-c-setup-project/)

Cuando defines las carpetas del instalador puedes agregar la de fuentes de windows

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para que se agregue alli al instalar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, la documentación es breve y funciona todo tal y cual lo dijiste. De nuevo, muchas gracias